# Android Studio Gradle Fail

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to build my android project, I got this error message.

Error while executing 'C:\Users\Chen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\cmake.exe' with arguments {-HC:\Users\Chen\Desktop\Project\IPS-Competition-master-326592647c34e3535eb78372bea8ec1c58ca6160\IPS-Competition-master-326592647c34e3535eb78372bea8ec1c58ca6160\IPS_Android\app -BC:\Users\Chen\Desktop\Project\IPS-Competition-master-326592647c34e3535eb78372bea8ec1c58ca6160\IPS-Competition-master-326592647c34e3535eb78372bea8ec1c58ca6160\IPS_Android\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Chen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Chen\Desktop\Project\IPS-Competition-master-326592647c34e3535eb78372bea8ec1c58ca6160\IPS-Competition-master-326592647c34e3535eb78372bea8ec1c58ca6160\IPS_Android\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Chen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Chen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=15 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=}

-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/**bin/clang.exe**

-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/**clang.exe -- broken**

**-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!**

CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation C:/Users/Chen/Desktop/Project/IPS-Competition-master-326592647c34e3535eb78372bea8ec1c58ca6160/IPS-Competition-master-326592647c34e3535eb78372bea8ec1c58ca6160/IPS_Android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi/CMakeFiles/3.6.0-rc2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake.tmp

**CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory**

I've installed CMAKE, LLDB, NDK. Can I get some help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install compiler driver of c++.